# iscroll page transition with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, iscroll4

I am trying to make iscroll work with jquery mobile for weeks.

I have make a quick sample based on the check-dom-changes exemple of iscroll (if you know other way i will take it too :)

Here are the code of pages i have make :

Page1 :
http://jsbin.com/ixomob/edit

And then the test page :
http://teraonline.be/street/iscrolltest/index.html

As you can see when you click the page2 link, the page2 appear but iscroll don't work anymore (you see native scrolling to the right instead), maybe they are another way to refresh the dom for the page2 but i don't have found how, because i am novice in javascript (i have read the other example on iscroll4 page, but maybe i don't have use them correctly).

I use the latest version of iscroll and jqm.

You are my last hope guys !

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to initialize the iScroll again and refresh it again, that is how I did realize iScroll on #page2 with JQuery Mobile... found no other way.